# How do I format a column to a specific type of date time in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am new to Google Sheets, and have a column that has values as below

```
Mon Oct 14 2019 10:09:58 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Mon Oct 14 2019 10:02:02 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Mon Oct 14 2019 09:47:13 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Mon Oct 14 2019 09:43:20 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Mon Oct 14 2019 09:35:20 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

I want to format them as `date/time`. What I saw in `Format > Number > More Formats` is

[image]

and I don't know how that to match with what I have.

Any help or guidance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to extract it. for example like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXT(DATE(MID(A1:A, 12, 4), MONTH(MID(A1:A, 5, 3)&1), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+")), "dd/mm/yyyy")&" "&REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+:\d+:\d+")))
```

[image: 0]